# I am not able to add Leap.dll and Leapcsharp.dll references in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, leap-motion

I am not able to add Leap.dll and Leapcsharp.dll from Leap SDK in given Visual studio project.I am using VS2012 express for Windows Desktop.

I have downloaded sdk from leapmotion site.I get error as "A reference could not be loaded.Please make sure that file is accessible and that is valid assembly or COM component."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433059/writing-custom-code-for-powerpoint

Answer (score 1):

Up one directory from the leap.dll and leapcsharp.dll is `LeapCSharp.NET3.5.dll` and `LeapCSharp.NET4.0.dll`.
([LeapDeveloperKit\LeapSDK\lib](https://developer.leapmotion.com/downloads))

These are the tools for Visual studio references.

If you want to use the leap.dll file then you'll need to use [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx)

EDIT:
Perhaps you could check out this [leap tutorial](http://irisclasson.com/2013/05/02/developing-for-leap-motion-in-c-tutorial-video-slides-and-code/), complete with [code examples](https://github.com/IrisClasson/Leap-Motion).

Here is a better [P/Invoke tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Using an application like [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) you can see all the methods available for your leap dll's.  These would be your entry points using P/Invoke.  There is also a [PInvoke assistance tool](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120) that will write your c# for you.

However, doing this with the `leap.dll`:

```
[DllImport("leap.dll")]
public static extern bool hasFocus();
```

Is the same as doing this with the `LeapCSharp.Net4.0` dll reference:

```
Leap.Controller con = new Controller();
var focus = con.HasFocus;
```

So you dont need both sets of DLL's.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have already added leapCSharp.NET3.5.dll.It is getting added properly.But Leaap.dll and LeapCSharp.dll from LeapDeveloperKit\LeapSDK\lib\x64 are not getting added.

I didn't get this P/Invoke.

Comment: So, to be clear, the leap and leapcsharp dll's do EXACTLY the same thing as the .NET dll's, if you have the .NET references, you dont need anything else.

Comment: please be sure to mark as answer if you dont have more questions.

Comment: can you help me with this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433059/writing-custom-code-for-powerpoint

Comment: Congratulations! Be sure to mark an answer if one of these posts helped!

Answer (score 1):

from [Leap Motion Developper Documentation](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/Languages/CSharpandUnity/Guides/Sample_CSharp_Tutorial.html)

> On Windows, make sure that Sample.exe,  and
>   either LeapCSharp.NET3.5.dll, or LeapCSharp.NET4.0.dll are in the
>   current directory. Use the libraries in the `lib\x86` directory for
>   32-bit projects. Use the libraries in the `lib\x64` directory for 64-bit
>   projects. [...]

You only need LeapCSharp.NET3.5.dll, or LeapCSharp.NET4.0.dll to compile your project. But you'll need the unmanaged libraries `Leap.dll` and `LeapCSharp.dll` to run your application (which are in `lib\x86` or `lib\x64` in the Leap SDK)

Personally I put these unmanaged libraries in a `App_Bin\<platform name>` folder (<platform name> = x84 or x64) under the solution directory and I use the following post-build command to copy them to the compiler output directory (e.g. `MyProject\bin\x64\Debug`)

```
xcopy /Y  /D "$(ProjectDir)..\App_Bin\$(PlatformName)\*.*" "$(ProjectDir)bin\$(PlatformName)\$(ConfigurationName)\"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433059/writing-custom-code-for-powerpoint

have a look..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

You have to add an existing item to your solution and select the files Leap.dll, LeapCSharp.dll from the folder:  LeapDeveloperKit\LeapSDK\lib(x86 or x64) and LeapCSharp.NET4.0.dll or LeapCSharp.NET3.5.dll (it depends if you are using framework 4 or 3.5 in your current project) from folder: LeapDeveloperKit\LeapSDK\lib. Then you have to do rigth click in each one of them and select the Properties option. You have to ensure that the "Copy to Output Directory" option is selected with "copy allwas" option (that's very important). Then you have to do rigth click in the References -> Add Reference -> Browse -> select your proyect (your current solution)-> select LeapCSharp.NET4.0.dll (from folder)-> ok. That's all.

or

See  [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Rn3q75mdns) min 11:29. She tells you better.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add the files Leap.dll and LeapCSharp.dll to your project.

And set the file property in Visual studio

> Copy to output directory = Copy Always;

Also add a reference to the project of LeapCSharp.NET4.0.dll or LeapCSharp.NET3.5.dll to your project. the reference must correspond to the machine type being used to debug or release the project. These files come to you within the SDK